# Unable to build apk using grunt build command

Tags: npm, gruntjs, oracle-jet

When I try to build apk for sample application in oracle JET using grunt command, I am getting below error.

> > Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
> >     Error: Cannot find module 'load-grunt-config'
> >        jit-grunt: Plugin for the "grunt" task not found.
> >
> > If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
> >
> > See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings
> >
> > Warning: Task "grunt" failed. Use --force to continue.
> >
> > Aborted due to warnings.
> >        Done.

Since I new to this concept, I don't know what to map using static mapping

IDE:NetBeans 8.2
Java: 1.8.0_111
Oracle JET Supoort Version: 0.10.1

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't give much information to work with, please see the official documentation regarding Oracle JET and hybrid developemt: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/jet230/jet/developer/GUID-C75CD8DC-5084-4831-BE1A-FFEE4EA8600C.htm#JETDG-GUID-C75CD8DC-5084-4831-BE1A-FFEE4EA8600C

Some required steps before trying to build.
Make sure you installed: **grunt-cli**, **bower**, **cordova** and the **Android SDK**

Did you scaffold an hybrid application using Yeoman?
ex: `yo oraclejet:hybrid app --appname="Sample NavBar" --template=navbar --platform=android`

What command (+ parameters) do you use to try and build your application?

Comment: I think  the Error is due latest version of cordova .Initially I installed cordova 6.0.0,Now having 3.5.0.
Now I am able to generate APK using grunt build --platform=andoid command